# Annotate Entity inside another Entity

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, flair

We have to extract an entity which is inside another entity, any idea on how can we annotate the training data to train a NER model for this task. We are using Flair model for custom entity training and prediction.

Ex: Text:  "" Address: 123, ABC Company, 4th floor, xyz street, state, country.""
We have a sample like this, where whole text itself is an entity of type "Address" and in the same text we have another entity called "Company Name".
For train a flair model, we are converting the data into BIEO format, not sure how to annotate the data and train the model.

Answer (score 0):

We came up with a solution to handle this scenario by training two models, one for address and other for company name.

Comment your approach on how we can handled this kind of a scenario in much better way.